# Deploy the same app to different regions on heroku?

Tags: heroku

I know heroku has different regions (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/regions), but it seems I can only select one region for one app.

How can I deploy the same app to different regions, so my users can be served by the nearest server (through the same domain)? Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

They don't have anything specifically in the platform for it. You might check this [tutorial](http://techbytes.anuragkapur.com/2015/05/heroku-for-highly-available-dropwizard.html) which has a "Global Traffic Management" section talking about how to use geo-routing from a CDN to Heroku.

Basically you have to build the whole infrastructure yourself. There is nothing out of the box.